# Creating ASP.NET Core SQL Cache table

Tags: caching, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to generate the Distributed SQL Server Cache for ASP.NET Core 2.0, using the CLI, but I only get an error. The instructions say to execute

```
dotnet sql-cache create <connection string>  <schema>  <table name>
```

but when I do, it simply responds with `No executable found matching command "dotnet-sql-cache"`.

I have installed `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlConfig.Tools 2.0.0` on that project. So it should work from the project root, no?

When I execute `dotnet -h`, I get `.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.2)`, etc. Surprisingly enough, `sql-cache` is not listed there among the SDK commands, alongside new, restore, run, migrate, etc. Shouldn't it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found installing certain Tools to be troublesome when I have used Nuget either by using the CLI or the package manager. In the past I have had to directly install a tool in the csproj file. Check your csproj file and see if the installation of the SqlConfig took hold. If it has not just add it and run a dotnet restore. Here is an example of how to "hard code" the tool. 
```

```
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference 
     Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlConfig.Tools" 
     Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Also, here is a link to where a better explanation to the [issue](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/c4f46271-c889-44ef-9b78-c062dc3ed3de.aspx).  It also recommends installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer if you have not already done so but I would try this solution first. Hope this helps.

Comment: My csproj file had an `ItemGroup` having `PackageReference`, but not one having `DotNetCliToolReference`. Adding the latter got this working for me. Great answer; thanks!

Comment: The Nuget seems a little bit outdated (Monday, May 7, 2018 (5/7/2018)). I guess installing `dotnet` is a better approach.

Answer (score 12):

I faced many troubles installing this tool, the only solution which worked for me was the one from @PAS, **but only after adding the exact .Net Core version** to the package installer.

Installing the latest one or even a slightly different one like 3.1.2 failed miserably.

So, the command line became :

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sql-cache --version 3.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance I used the command:

```
dotnet sql-cache create "Data Source=.\Ganimedes;Initial Catalog=DistCache;Integrated Security=True;" dbo SessionCache_Test
```

from PowerShell console. I  t's not neccesary to stay in Visual Studio to do this. The command is part of .Net Core SDK and you can use it from command line console (cmd, powershell, pwsh).

I have .Net Core 2.1 installed, this is the result of `dotnet --info`:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.502
 Commit:    c74ce8f29f

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.502\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.6
  Commit:  3f4f8eebd8

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.502 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the CLI itself recommend the following command for installing the required tooling (when called as it was not available):

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sql-cache
```